# How to change configuration of a custom coin after it has been Locked?

Tags: assets, accounts, signer

We have recently created a Custom coin on the market, and have realized that we did not pay the distributor wallet with the issuers wallet before locking the coin. Now we have a custom coin on the market with no way of distributing any coins.

We have set the master key weight to `0`, so trying to do so now fails every time since the issuer wallet has no weight in the signature.

Is there a way to delete the coin and start over, or a backdoor to send the distibutor wallet the issuers coins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once the account is locked, there is no way to unlock it or alter its state. It will remain locked and unusable forever. It is guaranteed on the protocol level.

You should start over with the new issuer account and issue new tokens. There is nothing that can be done here.